# What is data structure based for set

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

In C++, map is based on a black-red tree, thus, insert/delete function will cost O(logn), and hash_map is based on a hash.

But I'm wandering that what data structure is set based?

Set is sorted as map does, so, is set also based on a black-red tree?

How its key and value stored in that tree?

And if so, what's data structure for unorder_set? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no guarantee. The only thing that the standard mandates is the cost of the operations, so implementers are free to use whatever data structures they want. Typically `std::set` and `std::map` are balanced binary trees.

Also, `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` are hash tables. This I believe is actually guaranteed by the standard because you are allowed to specify the hashing function manually.

Answer (score 9):

The `set` and `map` types can be implemented pretty much however you'd like as long as it conforms to the time complexity requirements of the C++ specification, which bases the time complexities on a balanced binary search tree's time complexities. Although red/black trees are common for `map` and `set`, they're not the only options. You could have them implemented with AVL trees, B-trees, AA-trees, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you answered my other question once, thanks! This make sense to me. But if so, what difference between map and set?

Comment: I don't think splay trees guarantee the worst case access complexity required for the ordered associative containers.

Comment: @DietmarKühl- I can't find anything saying that the complexity is worst-case guaranteed, but I also can't find anything saying that it isn't. Do you have a reference either way?

Comment: @pippin1289: A `map<K, V>` is almost exactly a `set<pair<const K, V>>`. Looked at that way, `map` is a special case of `set`, and the more general structure is `set`. Consider, for example, a set of objects of a class with a `key()` accessor function. The annoyance of the behaviour of `find` will mostly be solved with c++1y

Comment: @templatetypedef: Perhaps this: 17.5.1.4 (structure.specifications) paragraph 7. "Complexity requirements specified in the library clauses are upper bounds, and implementations that provide better complexity guarantees satisfy the requirements."

Comment: @rici- Interesting! That actually disallows randomized and amortized-efficient data structures.

Comment: @rici: Note that the key in a `std::set<T>` is always entirely `const`! You can't implement a `std::map<K, V>` as `std::set<std::pair<K const, V>>` because you can't change the value. Also, for keys with equivalent `first` parts the `second` member would be considered.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I believe rici was purposefully being a little imprecise, for the purposes of the question, to show how `std::set` and `std::map` are very similar. (A set is just a map, minus the associated value, and likewise, a map is just a set, plus an associated value.)

Comment: @DietmarKühl: my understanding is that you can change a set member provided that it remains in the same equivalence class wrt the provided comparator. Certainly a custom comparator is required. I can't check the standard  right now, though, and I could be wrong. Independent of ther standard, it certainly seems to work.

Comment: @rici: The objects in a `std::set<T>` are of type `T const`. They may start their lives as `T const` in which case any attempt to get rid of the `const` results in undefined behavior. If `T` has a mutable member it could be muted but, indeed, any operation changing the elements in a `std::set<T>` should better not change their order as the result would also be undefined. Although I agree that the internal data structure used for `std::set<...>` and `std::map<...>` is likely the same, neither one replaces the other.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: afaik, the only indication that set objects might be of type `T const` is the last sentence of paragraph 5 of 23.2.4, "Keys in an associative container are immutable," which was added by the resolution of DR103. Despite the apparent firmness of that statement, the rationale in DR103 states that "If users need to modify elements, it is possible to use mutable members or const_cast." The sentence is now gone, as per DR 1214, whose author suggests "a hint for the reader that users may perform such changes in an explicit manner"...

Comment: ... a set iterator is a constant iterator, but that really says nothing. For one thing, the only definition of "constant iterator" is that it is an iterator which does not implement all the requirements of an output iterator, which says very little. But even if we take the words "constant iterator" at face value, that does not in any way imply that the referenced object is const. The rationale in DR103 (which says that const_cast is possible) seems to indicate that using const_cast to modify a set member is not UB (provided that it is still in the same EC wrt Comparator).

Answer (score 7):

The ordered associative containers, i.e, `std::set<...>` and `std::map<...>` and their "multi" versions, are node-based and have worst-case `O(ln n)` complexity. This implies that a balanced tree is used. In addition to the complexity neither pointers nor iterators are invalidated when the tree is mutated (except, of course, pointers or iterators to `erase()`d objects).

A B-tree sadly doesn't have the right iterator invalidation properties (and for maps requires duplicate storage of the key to get most of the advantage due to the force representation using a `std::pair<Key, Value>`). In practise it seems red/black trees are most effective but there are other possible balancing strategies, e.g., AVL trees. A skip list might also have the necessary properties. In either case, the standard doesn't mandate the exact implementation strategy.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there doesn't seem to be any guarantee of a specific implementation in the standard. However, the standard *does* make certain performance guarantees, such as insertion in O(log n) time for sets, which seems to be the real question that you are asking.